# Why is my filter not working on python SQLAlchemy Flask?

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a RESTful API on python using Flask and SQLAlchemy. Every other query I have written works, including using get and pagination on certain resources. But the problem is that I am having trouble getting one particular resource to work which should only get results by looking at `building_id`. The `building_id` is a foreign key which occurs multiple times on that particular table.

I do get a successful response but the data field is empty, i.e. number of result rows is 0.

I pretty much want this as SQL Alchemy
`SELECT * from building_unit where building_id = X order by building_id`

Thank you for any and all help.

> Model.py

```
class buildingUnit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'building_unit'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    building_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    unit_number = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    beds = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    baths = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    sqft = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    def __init__(self, id, building_id, unit_number, beds, baths, sqft, price):
        self.id = id
        self.building_id = building_id
        self.unit_number = unit_number
        self.beds = beds
        self.baths = baths
        self.sqft = sqft
        self.price = price
class buildingUnitSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    building_id = fields.Integer()
    unit_number = fields.String(required = False)
    beds = fields.Integer(required = False)
    baths = fields.Float(required = False)
    sqft = fields.Float(required = False)
    price = fields.Float(required = False)
```

> building_unit.py

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from Model import db, buildingUnit, buildingUnitSchema
building_unit_schema = buildingUnitSchema()

class buildingUnitSingleResource(Resource):
    def get(self, building_id):
        building_unit = buildingUnit.query.filter(buildingUnit.building_id == building_id)
        building_unit = building_unit_schema.dump(building_unit).data
        return {'status': 'success', 'data': building_unit}, 200
```

> app.py Route

```
api.add_resource(buildingUnitSingleResource, '/building_unit/<int:building_id>')
```

Comment: Why do you need that order in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems to be that since a filter will return more than one result (unlike `get(arg)` which only applies on primary key), I have to set `many=True` when creating `buildingUnitSchema`

`buildings_unit_schema = buildingUnitSchema(many=True)`

Well that's my understanding of why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
building_unit = buildingUnit.query.get(building_id)
```